# Need help figuring out why this sqlcommand EsecuteReader fails in .NET 4.5 and VS 2012 but not in .NET 3.5 and VS 2008

Tags: vb.net

H,
This section of the code is failing

`Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(CType(docRead("document"), Byte()), 0, 999999999)`

I am trying to figure this out.  The legacy VS 2008 code works fine but after converting to VS 2012 the code throws the error - `The sum of offset and count is greater than the length of the buffer.`
  Any and all help with this is appreciated.

Public Sub ViewDoc(ByVal docid As Integer)
        Dim dbRead As SqlDataReader
        Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection
        Dim docRead As SqlDataReader
        Try

```
        'Dim connStr As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("sqlConnectionString")
        'Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
        sqlConn = utls.NewOpenConnection
        Dim docinfosql As String = "SELECT Contenttype FROM VW_Rev_DocInfo WHERE DocInfoid = " & docid
        Dim docsql As String = "select Document from vw_Documents WHERE DocInfoid = " & docid
        Dim dbComn As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(docinfosql, sqlConn)
        Dim docComn As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(docsql, sqlConn)
        'sqlConn.Open()
        dbRead = dbComn.ExecuteReader
        Dim contenttype As String = ""
        While dbRead.Read
            contenttype = dbRead("Contenttype").ToString.Trim
        End While
        dbRead.Close()
        docRead = docComn.ExecuteReader
        Current.Response.Clear()
        Current.Response.ContentType = contenttype
        Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "")
        While docRead.Read
            Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(CType(docRead("document"), Byte()), 0, 999999999)
        End While

        Current.Response.Flush()
        Current.Response.End()
    Catch Ex As Exception
        'added exception method if Thread was being aborted exception is raised then response write is not available
        If Not Ex.Message = "Thread was being aborted." Then
            Throw
        End If
    Finally
        If Not sqlConn Is Nothing Then
            If Not sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                sqlConn.Close()
            End If
        End If

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `Array.Length` instead of hard coded `999999999`?  That way you are always writing the correct number of bytes instead of relying on the size of the array exactly matching your magic number.

Answer (score 0):

As you (presumably) have access to the compiled code have you looked at the generated IL using any of the many free decompilers that are out there such as:

- Just Decompile
- DotPeek
- IL Spy
- etc.

See what the difference is and perhaps some project compat settings will help you here.

Comment: I notice that when I change the code to something like this:Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(CType(docRead("document"), Byte()), 0, 9999) it works fine.  I think I need to find a way to specify the size of the current stream